# storing and accessing with matrices of more than two dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am using `ode45` to solve a system with 4 variables. For each time I execute the code:

```
[t y] = ode45(@func, tspan, y0);
```

`t` will be a one dimensional matrix, while `y` will be a 2 dimensional matrix, with 4 columns, each of which is the solution for one of the variables in question.

I want to run multiple trials of this, and keep them in a 3D matrix `my_y_results` and `my_t_results`. I want to be able to, for example, plot the final value of a certain variable for a particular initial condition, as I change the initial condition. How would I do this?

So, on each iteration of the loop below, I want to place the new values in a new matrix.

```
for i = 1:1:10
    y0 = **some value**
    [t_temp, y_temp] = ode45(@func, tspan, y0);
    my_t_results = **something**
    my_y_results = *something* //your code here
end
```

Also, how would I access the different values after setting them? For example, to get the last value of the variable y(1) for each of the 10 trials, what code would I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Higher dimensions can be accessed similar to the usual row and column dimensions. Let's assume `t` is Nx1 and `y` is Nx4, and that we are running M trials (note that each trial will have to have the same number of points, N, in order to store the data in a 3-dimensional array).

Your array `my_t_results` doesn't have to be 3-dimensional and can simply be NxM, where each column is the time vector for a different trial.

The array `my_y_results` would be Nx4xM and can be defined in MATLAB with:

`my_y_results = zeros(N,4,M);`

At the end of each i'th trial you would store the results like this:

`my_y_results(:,:,i) = y;`

And of course accessing the data is similar:

`y_i = my_y_results(:,:,i);`

Comment: Note you aren't limited to 3 dimensions either!